# Is it possible to generate 3 characters long unique id using the shortid?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I am using this code to generate unique ids.

```
const shortid = require('shortid');
 
console.log(shortid.generate());
```

This is giving me ids like

```
GaznPlpMR
uucCTr9p8
```

But I want to generate short ids like

```
qnf
cds
tri
```

Comment: There isn't very many three-character combinations, so your risk of repeated ids will be higher and you may need to handle it somehow. This is much less of an issue with longer ids...

Comment: Also why do you care. Also shortid seems to have been deprecated for https://github.com/ai/nanoid

Comment: You could use the [substring() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get just three characters, but as sabik noted there is a definite risk of repeated ids.

Comment: You could use `nanoid(3)` but the collision probability might be unacceptable https://zelark.github.io/nano-id-cc/

Comment: But why do you _want_ 3-letters IDs?

Comment: I am making a URL shortener. By default, it's 7-14 characters long. So in starting I only want it 3 characters long.